# Simple Python Script not Executing Properly

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

The code is as follows:

```
    fh = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix = '.py')
    stream = io.open(fh.name,'w',newline='\r\n')
    stream.write(unicode(script))
    stream.flush()
    stream.close()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [path,fh.name], 
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.stderr.close()
    out = proc.stdout.readline()
    print out
```

script is a string which contains the subprocess code, in this case a simple hello world. Since it has unix file endings, I had to use io.open in order to write it properly for windows. path is the path to the python.exe on my machine. The file is generated and looks fine in notepad:

```
    def main():
        print 'hello world'
```

However, when I run the program, the subprocess executes and does nothing.
Its not a problem with the executable path, I've tested it with other programs, so it must be with either the temp file itself, or the text within it. Delete is set to false in order to check the contents of the file for debugging. Is there anything glaringly wrong with this code? I'm a bit new to using Popen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your program is that when you specify `shell=True` , you need to provide the entire command as a string, not a list.

Given that, there is really no need for you to use `shell=True` , also, unless absolutely neccessary, you should not use `shell=True` , its a security hazard, this is given in the [documentation as well -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

> Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is **strongly discouraged** in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

Also, if you do not want to use `stdin` / `stderr` (since you are closing those off as soon as you start the process) , there is no need to use `PIPE` for them.

Example -

```
fh = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix = '.py')
stream = io.open(fh.name,'w',newline='\r\n')
stream.write(unicode(script))
stream.flush()
stream.close()
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [path,fh.name], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
out = proc.stdout.readline()
print out
```

---

Also, the script -

```
def main():
    print 'hello world'
```

would not work, since you need to call `main()` for it to run.

Comment: Ok so update: I pasted the temporary file's contents into a new file and tried to execute it through the Python IDE, and nothing happened as well, the program terminated with no output. This leads me to believe that there is a problem with the script translation from unix to windows

Comment: Yea, you are not calling `main()` in the script?

Comment: The IDE im working with automatically calls main when it runs a script

Comment: not `python.exe` , ide may call, `python.exe` would not. Try calling it at the last line of the script.